# Capture first packet of established TCP connection with iptables?

Tags: iptables, conntrack

I'm looking for a way to examine the *first packet only* of a newly established TCP connection (the first packet with actual payload, that is). Is there a way to do this with iptables? Matching ESTABLISHED packets would match  all packets of a connection after handshake, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using (abusing) `iptables`, to be more specific: `connbytes` match and `NFQUEUE` target. `connbytes` allows you to match the Nth packet in the connection and `NFQUEUE` is a mechanism for passing packets matching an iptables rule to userspace program. Furthermore: you'll have to use some program which whill be receiving relevant packets from the kernel and processing them.

### iptables

I'm assuming here that you are interested in capturing the packets server-side (that can be changed if you are interested in client-side capturing). In that case we'll need to capture the **3-rd incoming** packet for each connection (i.e. the first incoming packet after the three-way handshake) and put the packet in a netfilter queue (queue #1 in this case).

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -m connbytes --connbytes-mode packets --connbytes-dir original --connbytes 3:3 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

As soon as a packet matches this rule, it will be passed to the userspace program bound to the queue #1. The program can then examine the packet and afterwards decide to accept it or drop it.

### The program

You will need a program which will receive the packets in userspace using the [`libnetfilter_queue` library](http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/). Bindings for the library are available in different languages. The following is a sample program written in python:

```py
import struct

from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

def ip_to_string(ip):
        return ".".join(map(lambda n: str(ip>>n & 0xff), [24,16,8,0]))

def print_and_accept(pkt):
        pl = pkt.get_payload()
        src_ip = struct.unpack('>I', pl[12:16])[0]
        tcp_offset = (struct.unpack('>B', pl[0:1])[0] & 0xf) * 4
        tmp = struct.unpack('>B', pl[tcp_offset+12:tcp_offset+13])[0]
        data_offset = ((tmp & 0xf0) >> 4) * 4
        src_port = struct.unpack('>H', pl[tcp_offset+0:tcp_offset+2])[0]
        data = pl[tcp_offset + data_offset:]
        print 'from {}:{}, "{}"'.format(ip_to_string(src_ip), src_port, data)
        pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
        nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print
```

The program assumes that the queued packets will be IPv4 TCP packets and prints the source ip:port pair and the TCP payload of the packet.

### Caveats

1. You can never be sure that the first data packet will have the complete TLS client hello - TCP can fragment the stream as it likes and it is not impossible to receive a single byte in the first data packet.
2. [TCP Fast Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open) will break the logic of this approach. If it is enabled, the initial three-way handshake may already transfer data. But TFO is disabled by default on almost every device for now.
3. Care must be taken when using `NFQUEUE` target: if the userspace program bound to the queue hangs, crashes or is slow to process packets, those will be dropped/stuck and the service bound to the specified port will become unreachable. You can pass the `--queue-bypass` option to the `NFQUEUE` target to `ACCEPT` the matched packets if no userspace program is bound to the specified queue: this should help with the problem of the program crashing but won't help with a hung or slow program.

Answer (score 2):

> Matching ESTABLISHED packets would match all packets of a connection
>   after handshake, right?

Right !

Not sure what you mean by "capture". `iptables` is a thing, network packet capture (`tcpdump`) is another thing.

Assuming that my understanding is "log only new connections", you will have to log only rules matching the `NEW` state.

Let's use a sample case where we want to log only new connections for an icmp (ping) request :

```
# Define LOG settings
iptables -N LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -A LOG_ACCEPT -j LOG --log-prefix '[IPTABLES ACCEPT] :'
iptables -A LOG_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d 192.168.0.47 -m state --state NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d 192.168.0.47 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Here we just `LOG` when `NEW` connection is established. So we can send 1000+ ping (from the same source host), only the first packet will be logged :

```
Apr  4 21:28:17 UBN-1 kernel: [78512.613705] [IPTABLES ACCEPT] :IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:e4:d1:06:10:60:4b:69:7e:fd:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.39 DST=192.168.0.47 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=32571 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=47088
```

---

If you put `LOG_ACCEPT` in the `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` rule :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d 192.168.0.47 -m state --state NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d 192.168.0.47 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j LOG_ACCEPT
```

then each ping request will be logged. So 1000+ ping (from the same source host) will generate 1000+ entries in the log :

```
Apr  4 21:33:49 UBN-1 kernel: [78844.130615] [IPTABLES ACCEPT] :IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:e4:d1:06:10:60:4b:69:7e:fd:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.39 DST=192.168.0.47 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=244 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=47092
Apr  4 21:33:50 UBN-1 kernel: [78845.130551] [IPTABLES ACCEPT] :IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:e4:d1:06:10:60:4b:69:7e:fd:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.39 DST=192.168.0.47 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=247 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=47093
Apr  4 21:33:51 UBN-1 kernel: [78846.131295] [IPTABLES ACCEPT] :IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:e4:d1:06:10:60:4b:69:7e:fd:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.39 DST=192.168.0.47 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=250 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=47094
Apr  4 21:33:52 UBN-1 kernel: [78847.132160] [IPTABLES ACCEPT] :IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:e4:d1:06:10:60:4b:69:7e:fd:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.39 DST=192.168.0.47 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=252 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=47095
......
......
```

---

Hope i have understood the question !

Comment: But matching NEW would give me the first handshake packet, i.e. SYN on TCP, correct? What I'm interested in is the first packet of the communications _after_ the handshake (specifically, a TLS client hello in my case) -- sorry for being rather unclear about my goals.

Comment: @N.A Correct. Still unsure about what you want : iptables logging or packet capture ?

Comment: Logging, not capture as in tcpdump -- sorry about that. Specifically, as said, I'd like to log all TLS client hellos.

Comment: @N.A Ok. You cannot do this just using iptables logging. Follow @Evan Anderson advice to achieve this. As i was guessing, `tcpdump` is what you need and is your best friend in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're looking for with stock `iptables`. You'd need to write some layer 7 inspection code.

An alternative, if you're willing to put up with some post processing, would be to capture traffic with `tcpdump` into PCAP files, parse them for the packets you're looking for, and throw away the rest. I know that Wireshark's SSL dissector and a display filter could get what you're looking for.

If you didn't mind that your captures would lag behind realtime a bit you could easily use `tcpdump` to capture the traffic to rotating PCAP files. You could run a script that monitors for completed PCAP files and parses them with `tshark` and a display filter to write out only what you're looking for to new PCAP files.